# Play HTML5 video inline on iOS but still allow full-screen

Tags: html, ios, video, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

I have a React app with a  tag. At first, the video played automatically in full-screen. After I added `playsinline`, the video plays in place, the way I wanted.

Now, the full-screen button does not respond. Any way to make it work and still make it play inline by default?

Comment: Have you tried "allowFullScreen" param?

Comment: @RoHaN it looks that "allowFullScreen" is for an iframe, which I don't have.